# Pascal компилятор для Sublime Text 2

Tags: pascal, sublime-text, плагин

Существует ли плагин для текстового редактора `Sublime Text 2` для работы с `Pascal`?

Интересует подсветка, возможность компилировать и видеть ошибки компиляции.

Comment: В лучшем случай недоделанный набор сниппетов https://github.com/diniremix/sublime-pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот то, что Вам нужно - http://lepeta.net/po/windows-po/pishem-na-pascal-v-sublime-text-2.html

Comment: Судя по описанию — то, что нужно. Но, к счастью, подошел к концу мой курс обучения этому языку и, надеюсь, не увижу его в дальнейшем. Спасибо `:)`